# How to keep a music playing running even I change the routing in angular (ts)?

Tags: angular, angularjs, routes, spotify, audio-player

I have an *Angular 14* application that includes a music player component. The music player component starts playing music when the user clicks a play button. However, when the user navigates to another page using the Angular router, the music player component is destroyed and the music stops playing.

I want to keep the music player component running even when the user changes the routing in the application. I also want to ensure that the component is properly destroyed when it is no longer needed.

that' my routing

```
  {path:"login", component:LoginComponent},
  {path:"signup", component:SignupComponent},
  {path : '',
    component : PrimaryLayoutComponent,
    children:[
      {path:"" , component:HomeComponent},
      {path:"all-albums" , component:ListAlbumsComponent},
      {path:"albumid" , component:SingleAlbumComponent},
      {path:"all-artists" , component:ListArtistsComponent},
    ]
  }
```

and the music player component is in PrimaryLayoutComponent to avoid rendering every time

I have tried using a service to manage the state of the music player and loading the music player component in a way that it is not destroyed when the route changes. However,doen't work and I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: can you share a stackblitz code